# Multiple Columns in Java

Tags: java

In Java, is it possible for me to maintain a table with multiple columns? If so,how? If there are more than one ways, which way is the best way?

Comment: Is this for a Java desktop app with the Swing UI?

Comment: More detail needed? A Table in a GUI (JTable) or do you have some tabular data?

Comment: There is no GUI involved here at all..

Comment: Or an HTML table, or ...  'cmon @hari - don't make us play guessing games.

Comment: He could also mean an embedded database, or even arrays. Show us an example of what you would call a table with a single column, and then someone might be able to expand on it to make it multiple columns.

Comment: Maybe an array of array would be enough?

Comment: I want the table to be displayed on a terminal..

Comment: Is multi-dimensional array possible in java?I thought it was possible only in C#

Comment: Yes multi-dimensional arrays are possible, although it would actually be an array of arrays. Thus you could do `int i[][] = new int[5][3]; int x = i[0].length;`, i.e. you access the first array and get its length.

Comment: Got it..Thanks guys..Multi-dimensional arraylists are also possible i believe..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming, you're talking about a datamodel for your table:

**arrays**

```
Object[][] table = new Object[rows][columns];
table[1][3] = "Value for row 2, column 4";
```

This is the easiest approach but somewhat difficult to handle. Personally, I don't like index arithmetics...

**Collections**

```
List<List<Object>> table = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();
List<Object> row = new ArrayList<Object>();
row.add("Value for first row, first column");
row.add("Value for first row, second column");
table.add(new ArrayList<Object>()); // add first row
```

No index arithmetics but a lot of code to write...

**Objects**

```
public class DataSet {
  private Object col1;
  private Object col2;
  // ...
  // constructor, getters, setters, and so on
}

List<DataSet> table = new ArrayList<DataSet>();
table.add(new DataSet(/* ... */));  // add another row
```

I'd prefer this approach - each row is represented by an instance of DataSet.

Comment: Why - downvote? Thought, that was exactly what hari wanted - datastructures to store table data...

Comment: **ROTFL** :) My first accept with a negative vote ratio !! This should be worth a badge

Comment: Upvote for guessing most of what the asker wanted with so little info.

Answer (score 1):

Swing provides a pretty decent tool for this, namely JTable:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Comment: @hari as the other guys mentioned, it is very hard to tell what you are actually asking. Maybe you should add that information to the question?